# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT ajax file upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a  ajax form file upload in my jquery. I have tested my code on many computers and browsers and it doesnt seem to be working on one chrome+windows 8 machine. It gives an error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT
```

Also, I have image/video upload in that php file. The image upload works fine, but the video causes problems in that PC. Otherwise, the video works fine on all others pcs.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

this is an old treat, but i found this, searching for an answer to the same problem, the problem was upload files to http site, i always get

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT
```

i must add an ssl cert to the site (https) and then the files are upload correctly.